# Problems launching Java RMI server on JDK 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, rmi, fibonacci

This is a follow up to my problem described in:

- [Cannot launch RMI Fibonacci server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937415/cannot-launch-rmi-fibonacci-server)

To sum up, I have a very basic server that I wish to launch using Java RMI. In my previous question I was advised to use a Securtity group, launch the RMI in the Main and to adapt my code to the changes in java 1.7 after release 21:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/enhancements-7.html

Following is the code (simplified version!):

**FibonacciServer.java:**

```
public class FibonacciServer {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }

        try{
            Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind("fibonacci", fib);

            System.out.println("Fibonacci Server ready.");
        }catch(RemoteException rex){
            System.err.println("Exception in Fibonacci.main " + rex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fibonacci.java:**

```
public class Fibonacci extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IFibonacci{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4300545841720809981L;

    public Fibonacci() throws RemoteException{
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger getFibonacci(int n) throws RemoteException {
        return getFibonacci(new BigInteger(Long.toString(n)));
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger getFibonacci(BigInteger n) throws RemoteException {
        BigInteger computation = someImportantComputation;
        return computation;
    }

}
```

**IFibonacci.java:**

```
public interface IFibonacci extends Remote{
    public BigInteger getFibonacci(int n) throws RemoteException;
    public BigInteger getFibonacci(BigInteger n) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Last but not least, here is my **server.policy** file:

```
grant{
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

My system specs are:

- Linux Mint
- java version "1.7.0_51"
- Eclipse Kepler
- Netbeans 7.4

I am using both Eclipse and Netbeans. Why? I am desperate ... that is why.

Steps that I am taking:

1. start the rmi registry by opening a terminal and typing `rmiregistry`. I am confused, having in mind I already do this in my `FibonacciServer.java` class, do I still have to do it here?
2. Run the program using the arguments `-Djava.security.policy=server.policy`
3. See everything crash and fall apart.

This is the error message that I get:

```
Exception in Fibonacci.main java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fiboserver.IFibonacci
```

I have also tried running with `-Djava.security.policy=server.policy -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false` (which is not recommended, but I really do not see a way out of it) but I still get the exact same error.

I know for sure that Java is finding the `server.policy` file, so the error has to be somewhere else, but I have no idea on what could be wrong.

Therefore I have the following questions:

- How can I fix it?
- Is there a way for me to run the code with using the `-Djava.security.policy=server.policy` flag? Is there a way to include that in the code?

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate. In fact, I even mention that one discussion here. I use the same code, but I am attacking the problem on a different angle, thus a new discussion.

Comment: It is an exact duplicate. Some code, same problem, same solution.